# Android screen reader skips a view and reads elements below

Tags: android, accessibility, focus

I have following layout

[image]

Red is background video which needs to be paused by clicking on it, so it has to be focusable.
Now my problem is when i focus (by taping on it) on a text view, with talkback enabled, it gets focus for a split second (you can see the green outline), but then it immediately jumps to the video underneath, so the screen reader doesn't even have the time to read the content of the text view.

It only happens when tapping on a text view, button works as expected so focus doesn't "traverse" multiple views. I also noticed that by adding click listener (or clickable property) to the text view, focus doesn't skip it anymore (it stops at the text view) but then i get "Double tap to " line

Is there any way to make the screen reader stop at the text view without "jumping" automatically to the view bellow ?